# PhantomJs Open 2 pages

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Using phantomJs I am trying get the html content of 2 pages. One page with userAgent set and one without. Here is the code...

```
var url = "http://libertyplus.co.uk";
//var url = "http://facebook.com";

var page1 = require('webpage').create();
var page2 = require('webpage').create();

page1.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page1.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page2.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;

var content = new Array;

page1.open(url, function(status){
    if(status == 'success'){
        content.push(page1.content);
    }
});

page2.open(url, function(status){
    if(status == 'success'){
        content.push(page2.content);
    }
});

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(content)); 
    phantom.exit();
}, 2500);
```

This works perfectly when url is `http://www.libertyplus.co.uk` and I get both contents as expected, but when I change the url to `http://facebook.com`, I get an empty array.

Comment: `http://facebook.com` will probably redirect to `https://www.facebook.com` or similar. Maybe there is some problem. Also it might not have loaded the page after 2,5 seconds. Better output the response in the callback of `page.open()`.

Comment: Additionally, please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.